# Multiplying doubles

Tags: java, multiplication

I searched and couldn't find anything as simple as my example. Can anyone please tell me why I'm getting this error?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Shopping {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What is the item name?");
        String itemName = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What is the item price?");
        double itemPrice = keyboard.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("What is the item quantity?");
        double itemQuantity = keyboard.nextFloat();
        double total = itemQuantity * itemPrice;
        System.out.printf("%d x %s @ $%d Total $%d",itemQuantity,itemName,itemPrice,total);
    } //main

} // class Shopping
```

Error when running:

```
java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.Double
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Formatter.java:4302)
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printInteger(Formatter.java:2793)
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:2747)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2520)
    at java.io.PrintStream.format(PrintStream.java:970)
    at java.io.PrintStream.printf(PrintStream.java:871)
    at Shopping.main(Shopping.java:13)
```

I originally set itemQuantity as int, but this threw up the error. I thought it was because of the mismatched types, but after I corrected it, the error still occurred.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're trying to format a double using `%d`, which is the format key for digit. Use `%f` for floating point values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this to

```
System.out.printf("%f x %s @ $%f Total $%f",itemQuantity,itemName,itemPrice,total);
```

Please note that `%d` is for decimal, you can refer [oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html)

Answer (score 0):

%d is using for integer, for float and double you have to use %f 
for this You are getting this type of error.
Try this.

```
 System.out.printf("%f x %s @ $%f Total $%f",itemQuantity,itemName,itemPrice,total);
```